# How to implement threading in client generated by axis to make multiple requests to a webservice using java

Tags: java, web-services, axis, middleware

I have an array list of request objects. I run them in a for loop and inside the loop I call the webservice and add the response object to another array list. I need to implement threading so that I can send multiple request to the web service.

Comment: You can start by showing some code of what you've already done/tried. Are you across the Java concurrency APIs?

Comment: for (Iterator<RefundOrderRequest> iterator = refundOrderRequestList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   RefundOrderRequest refundOrderRequest1 = (RefundOrderRequest) iterator
     .next();
   response = soapRequest.refundOrder(refundOrderRequest1);
   refundOrderResponseList.add(response);
   
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried this myself however thought it might be interesting so I played around with it, hope it does what you want:

```
List<RefundOrderResponse> responses = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<RefundOrderResponse>());

Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
CompletionService<RefundOrderResponse> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<RefundOrderResponse>(e);

// Create some futures based on the requests we have that we want processed
List<Future<RefundOrderResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<RefundOrderResponse>>();

for (final RefundOrderRequest request : requests)
{
    futures.add(ecs.submit(new Callable<RefundOrderResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public RefundOrderResponse call () throws Exception
        {
            // do the call to the web service here and return the response
            return soapWS.refundOrder(request);
        }
    }));
}

// Now we can process the response, note with a completion service we are assuming process order of responses is not very important.
for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
    responses.add(ecs.take().get());
}
```

I've used the Java CompletionService here, or more specifically the [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) (as it uses an executor to run in parrallel). It does assume that the processing of the response can be done in any order, which in this case is simply just adding them to a responses list. Not sure what you plan on doing with the responses list however you could just process them in the loop instead of adding them to a list.